# Máscara de campos dinâmico para telefone em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sei que tem máscaras em jquery, como por exemplo jQuery Masked Input, porém estou fazendo a manutenção de um sistema que foi desenvolvido por outro colega e infelizmente está dando conflitos no jquery que ele implementou:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Para tentar solucionar o conflito, tentei usar o código abaixo:

```
<script>var $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Mas infelizmente não funcionou, pois quando implemento outro jquery, alguns recursos deixam de funcionar. Tenho o código abaixo que fornece esse resultado:

```
 <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr class='linhas'>
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePessoaAutorizada[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo" value=""></td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px; width: 8%"><input type="text" name="DDD[]" class="form-control" placeholder="DDD" value="" maxlength="2"></td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="TelefoneCelularPessoaAutorizada[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Telefone celular" onkeypress="mascara(this, '#####-####')" maxlength="13"></td> <!-- data-inputmask="'alias': '(99)99999-9999'" -->
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="RGPessoaAutorizada[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value=""></td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais contatos</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
       function removeCampo() {
             $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
             $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
                if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }
             });
       }
       $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
         if ($('.linhas').length < 5) {
             novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
             novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
             novoCampo.find('select').val("");
             novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
             removeCampo();
           }
       });
     });
 </script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para evitar conflitos, gostaria de saber como faço para implementar a máscara em campos dinâmicos, mas desenvolvido em JavaScript e não em Jquery. Mergulhando no Google, encontrei essa solução:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mascara(t, mask){
 var i = t.value.length;
 var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
 var texto = mask.substring(i)
 if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
 t.value += texto.substring(0,1);
 }
 }
</script>
```

Funciona em partes, pois apresenta 02 problemas. O primeiro é que aceita também letras e o segundo é que, apesar do maxlength estar com valor de 13 caracteres, ele não está aceitando o valor informado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Segue um método para mascara de telefone.

Fonte [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15803006/4312593).

**Exemplo**

```js
function mask(o, f) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var v = mphone(o.value);
    if (v != o.value) {
      o.value = v;
    }
  }, 1);
}

function mphone(v) {
  var r = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
  r = r.replace(/^0/, "");
  if (r.length > 10) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
  } else if (r.length > 5) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
  } else if (r.length > 2) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/, "($1) $2");
  } else {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
  }
  return r;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onkeypress="mask(this, mphone);" onblur="mask(this, mphone);" />
```

Comment: Perfeito Netinho. Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Adapdado para o formato: (88) 9 9999-9999.

```js
function phoneMask(v) {

  let r = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
  r = r.replace(/^0/, "");

  if (r.length > 11) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
  } else if (r.length > 7) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
  } else if (r.length > 2) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/, "($1) $2");
  } else if (v.trim() !== "") {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
  }
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Fiz algumas modificações:
Precisei mudar o evento para keyup (além do fato do keypress ter sido descontinuado) pois o keypress pega sempre a string com um caractere a menos e para funcionar precisava também do onblur, algo que não ocorre com o keyup. Ajustes no código foram necessários para resolver isso e a questão do backspace ao retirar o “-” do número do telefone que ficava sempre voltando.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/windmateus/7tae9wps/1/)

```js
  function mascaraFone(event) {
    var valor = document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'];
    var retorno = valor.replace(/\D/g, "");
    retorno = retorno.replace(/^0/, "");
    if (retorno.length > 10) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 5) {
      if (retorno.length == 6 && event.code == "Backspace") { 
        // necessário pois senão o "-" fica sempre voltando ao dar backspace
        return; 
      } 
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 2) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/, "($1) $2");
    } else {
      if (retorno.length != 0) {
        retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'] = retorno;
  }
```

```html
<input id="telefone" onkeyup="mascaraFone(event)" />
```